# How much money is needed in my bank account for a Schengen visa?

Tags: germany, proof-provenance-of-funds, zimbabwean-citizens

I am from Zimbabwe and applying for Schengen visa (short term) for only 45 days.

How much money is needed in my bank account for me to be given a Schengen visa?

Comment: it depends which visa category you are looking for, can you clarify your question here

Comment: im applying for schengen visa (short term) for only 45 days

Comment: @AliAwan it also depends on what the traveler plans to do in the Schengen area. Some accommodations or activities require more money than others. It may also depend on the country evaluating the application. Leo: for 45 days you probably need at least a few thousand euros. But if you just deposit the money in your account for the purpose of showing the balance in the application, they'll suspect that the money isn't really yours, and they'll refuse you. Search on this site for *funds parking* if you'd like more information.

Comment: But my account i use it more often i usually deposit $50-$100 and sometimes $700 .So i dont know ,will they accept it?

Comment: Are you saying you have $700 to support yourself during this trip? That's roughly €630, which is €14 each day. What are you planning to eat? What are you planning to do between meals?

Comment: I am planning to add some more .But first i roughly want to know the prices of food per day and other expenses .

Answer (score 1):

One of the key criteria for short term visit visas (not just for Schengen, but almost anywhere) is that the applicant must be able to support themselves (and their dependents) and **should not be a burden on the state**. There are many ways to show proof of support; for example, you could have a sponsor that can provide an affidavit of support, your ticket and accommodation can be pre-paid by someone else.  However, in the end the application is judged on **your individual circumstances**.

If you are unable to support yourself for the duration of the trip, do not try to borrow money and place it in your account. This is called funds parking and is almost guaranteed to get your application rejected.

The amount of funds required vary from country to country and also based on what is the purpose and duration of your trip; there is no "fixed amount".

More to the point, if your bank account has large sum of money, and no activity; or it doesn't match the profile of someone in your economic / social status, this is also cause for alarm and possible rejection.

Comment: so will it be necessary for the one inviting me to produce her own bank avcount showing that she will be responsible for the expense?

Comment: If you are being invited by a person, they have to prepare an affidavit of support which includes (in addition to their financial details) their status in the country, their relationship with you, the purpose and duration of your stay, what specifically is the sponsor helping with (for example, are they providing you accommodation? Are they fully financially supporting your trip, etc.) This letter is then submitted to the embassy.

Comment: Im invited by my girlfriend and shes paying my ticket and my hotel reservation and food when im the country and also shes working as a nurse in Germany .